# Extending MVC FoolProof validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I would like to use **[MVC FoolProof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)** in my MVC 3 application.

I need a Numeric validation and also accepts N/A or n/a. So i decided to create my own custom validation attribute like **NumericAllowNAAttribute** and add a jQuery validation custom adopter method.

I revisited MVC Foolproof and decided to use that, since it has other helpful method build already. I want those also. Now how can i write a CustomValidationAttribute that works on client side using jQuery validate and Server side?

Searched google on extending MVC Foolproof i didnt get any.

> Is any one came across extending or implementing this kind of
>   validation works in server and client with jQuery validation plugin?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend foolproof MVC by defining a new attribute that inherits ContingentValidationAttribute (or one of the other attributes in foolproof, but continent is pretty close to barebones).

You will need to define the following method overrides.

```
public override bool IsValid(object value, object dependentValue, object container)
protected override IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetClientValidationParameters()
public override string ClientTypeName
```

ClientTypeName string value is used by jquery unobtrusive validation.

Also, be sure to register your adapter with DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider (foolproof does it in the constructor for their classes).

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyCustomValidationAttribute), typeof(FoolproofValidator));
```

Once you've defined your server-side validation logic you will need to register with jquery unobtrusive validation on the client-side:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("clienttypenameyouemitontheserver", function(value, element, params) {
    // perform your checks here and return true or false
    return true; 
});

var $Unob = $.validator.unobtrusive;
$Unob.adapters.add("clienttypenameyouemitontheserver", ["param1", "param2", "paramZ"], function (options) {
    var value = {
        param1: options.params.param1,
        param2: options.params.param2,
        paramZ: options.params.paramZ
    };
    setValidationValues(options, "clienttypenameyouemitontheserver", value);
});
```

Comment: You'll also need to register the attribute with Foolproof, e.g. `static MyCustomValidationAttribute() { Register.Attribute(typeof(MyCustomValidationAttribute)); }`.